# Which one is grammatically correct, “в Южную Корею” or “в Южная Корею”?

Tags: прилагательные, винительный-падеж

I had been thinking “в Южную Корею” is the right way before I heard “в Южная Корею” in a movie and after searching I found both ways abound in examples.

UPDATE: It was a Japanese movie, 君よ憤怒の河を渉れ, dubbed by Мосфильм under the title Опасная погоня. The line can be found at https://youtu.be/P1g_uS7abmk?t=8723. In fact I had trouble understanding the whole line, which to my ears sounded like “Тоже на (?) лететь в ... спешу ...”.

Comment: "в Южную Корею" is the right one

Comment: It's possible that you HEARD южная was pronounced similar to южную, since the last syllable is unstressed (maybe the speech was fast). It's not the matter of grammar, but pronounciation of sounds. But a native speaker hears the difference of course.

Comment: Added the link to the movie.

Comment: i vaguely remember watching this movie as a kid in a movie theater... so yes you are correct, the voice actor pronounced it almost like **Южная** or something in between, so i guess it was a slip of the tongue after all

Comment: I've actually opened the link and man pronounces the word as "Южнаю". I've never heard anyone pronounce it this way. To me, it seems that the actor started saying wrong word ("Южная" instead of "Южную") and then corrected himself, thus creating this weird "Южнаю".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the preposition **В** there're only **two** options, either *Prepositional* or *Accusative* case.

*Prepositional case* when **В** forms adverbial of location, which answers the question **где?** - **where (at)?** - **`в ЮжнОЙ КореЕ`, `в ПекинЕ`, `в КитаЕ`, `в городЕ`, `в селЕ`** etc.

*Accusative case* when **В** forms adverbial of destination (with verbs of motion or intent) which answers the question **куда?** - **to where? / whither?** - **`в ЮжнУЮ КореЮ`, `в Пекин`, `в Китай`, `в город`, `в село`** etc.

Anything else is either a mistake or a slip of the tongue.

After listening in to the dubbing i concede that it was pronounced almost like **Южная**, which may be attributed to a slip of the tongue.

The whole line goes

> Н.... я должен лететь в Южную Корею

**H...** here stands for interjection of hesitation, akin to the English **um**.

Answer (score 3):

Only the first form would be the correct one, you have to conjugate both words in this situation, since this geographical name is not treated as a word borrowed from another language (i.e. a foreign word). [Based on this source](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90), there could be a discussion if you would say в страну Южная Корея or в страну Южную Корею, however the second option you would find more often used in everyday life.

[pls. refer here for a brief explanation of conjugation of geographical names in Russian language](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)